# How do I configure a GitHub Actions workflow so it does not run on a tag push?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'd like to configure a GitHub Actions workflow so that it runs on branch pushes, but not tag pushes. I thought this would work:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags-ignore: ['**']
```

But then the workflow failed to run when I pushed a branch, too. Is there a way to configure it so that it runs on a branch push but not a tag push?

Comment: Do your tags have any specific pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unintuitively, to avoid the tags, you have to tell it to run on all the branches instead. See [its use in psycopg](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/blob/5681de9c42f916d5b2436ad9c6f47b79c8aeaa12/.github/workflows/tests.yml#L4-L8) for instance.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "*"
  pull_request:
  schedule:
    - cron: '48 6 * * *'
```

[The docs say](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore):

> If you define only tags/tag-ignore or only branches/branches-ignore, the workflow won't run for events affecting the undefined Git ref.

Comment: This is bizarre. Do you have a link to the docs?

Comment: Was looking it up back the docs, they had changed since I discovered how to use it. Answer updated.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it'd be useful when one wanted to also allow pull requests and cron jobs.

Comment: No, it's ok, look at the usage in psycopg repos. `cron` and `pull_requests` are sibling of `push`, not of `branches`.

Comment: Oooh, of course, I see. Thanks!